# Updating the DataGridView with an IF statement of another form (VB.NET)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, forms, visual-studio, if-statement

On my code let's say I have 2 forms

On the main one is the DataGridView, it contains a column called ActivityStatus, which displays if the member is either Stopped/On-going
I have a second form that I open by double clicking on a row, which gives me all the member's details, and at the bottom of the form there's a button that has a password; if written correctly, it should switch his ActivityStatus (if he's stopped; he'll become ongoing, vice versa)
Here's the code I wrote for it

In form 1:

```
Private Sub DGVData_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVData.CellContentDoubleClick
    Dim SV As New -- [FORM 2 NAME HERE]
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim Row As DataGridViewRow
        Row = DGVData.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        SV.ActivityChange = Row.Cells("ActivityStatus").Value.ToString
        SV.IDVerify = Row.Cells("ID").Value.ToString
        ED.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

In form 2:

```
Public Class StatusVertificationBox
Public Property ActivityChange As String
Public Property IDVerify As String

Private Sub StatusPassBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StatusPassBtn.Click
    If StatusPassTxt.Text = "password123" Then
        If ActivityChange = 1 Then
            Dim Ask As MsgBoxResult
            Ask = MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
            If Ask = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                Dim MakeActiveCmd As String = "UPDATE InitialTable " &
                                              "SET ActivityStatus = 0 " &
                                              "WHERE ID='" & IDVerify & "' "
                MsgBox("This member's membership has been stopped")
            ElseIf Ask = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                MsgBox("No modifications have been made")
            End If
        ElseIf ActivityChange = 0 Then
            Dim Ask As MsgBoxResult
            Ask = MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
            If Ask = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                Dim MakeInactiveCmd As String = "UPDATE InitialTable " &
                                              "SET ActivityStatus = 1 " &
                                              "WHERE ID='" & IDVerify & "' "
                MsgBox("This member's membership has been renewed")
            ElseIf Ask = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                MsgBox("No modifications have been made")
            End If
        End If
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect Password, please try again.")
        StatusPassTxt.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't understand where the issue is. The IF statement isn't working properly (the text displays on the MsgBox doesn't match the statement, and the value isn't changing at all on the datagridview)

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks for reading guys

**EDIT:** fixed things from the code, I improperly copied it, since I edited a few things to make it easier to you guys to understand, which made me miss out a few codes

**EDIT2:** I noticed that it ALWAYS follows the last IF statement that I put on it.. It's always following If ActivityChange = 0, even if (according to how it shows) it should show as 1.. I still don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
the variable `ActivityChange` is of type String. Therefore the comparison should be:

```
If StrComp(ActivityChange, "1") = 0 Then
  ...
```

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I already have that MsgBoxStyle.YesNo

I originally use an Arabic text in the MsgBox, so I had to edit it out for you guys to understand it... I forgot to re-copy the MsgBoxStyle.YesNo part

But yes, I do use that; and it's ineffective.

Comment: @JohnMay maybe you have to do comparisons of strings as shown in the code.